# Passing Item name for PayPal Client-side REST integration

Tags: rest, paypal, client-side, express-checkout

I'm using PayPal Client-side REST integration 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/client-side-REST-integration/

and I would like to pass **item name** together with total and currency.

The *item_name* is obviously available for standard HTML forms
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/

I'm unable to find a proper way when working with client-side Express Checkout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developer documentation will have the information an adding an object and passing the information you're looking for. The document will show the reference for the Payments API along with a sample request.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment

Comment: Thanks a lot PP_MSI_Lehi!

Here's how to add the description:
`"transactions": [
  {
    "amount": {
      "total": "3.00",
      "currency": "EUR"
    },
    "description": "Cappuccino",
    "invoice_number": "48787589673",
  }
]`